# UltiDev IP address binding

Tags: android, ultidev

I am trying to create a web service for my android application. The web service is supposed to run on UltiDev, the issue i get is when i try to access the web service through a local android emulator. I was advised to change the url of the web service to http://10.0.2.2:portnumber/serviceName but when i attempt to make this change i get an error in UltiDev. It turns out that i have to bind the port first before i can do this, however UltiDev does not allow me to do this. This is the error i get. Sorry i can't post the actual image because i need reputation points first.

Failed to register application because System.ApplicationException: Unable to register application because not all required applications settings are specified: Listen endpoints are either not specified or are already taken by other applications.

at UWS.Configuration.WebAppConfigEntry.ApplyFinalDefaultsAndValidateBeforeSaving()
.....

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify whether you are trying to do this programmatically, or using UWS Explorer UI? Please attach a screenshot - it always helps.
In case you use UWS Explorer, the screenshot below shows how to add a port binding. If you click "Specify host name or IP address" radiobutton, you will be able to specify an IP address.

If you do all that, but then you still get the same error, it means your system acts as if all IP+ports are already taken, which often is caused by security software, like firewall+antiviruses.

[image]